# Heroku app build error upstream dependency conflict

Tags: reactjs, heroku, conflict

My app is not building on heroku with resulting in this error. This does not happen on Netlify, only heroku. Is there a conflict with react dependencies with ^ symbol?

```
npm ERR! While resolving: videostream-react-js@0.1.0
       npm ERR! Found: @material-ui/core@4.11.3
       npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
       npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.11.3" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer @material-ui/core@"4.0.1" from material-table@1.69.2
       npm ERR! node_modules/material-table
       npm ERR!   material-table@"^1.69.2" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: For my app it happens on Netlify as well

Answer (score 0):

Adding a late response since I stumbled the same issue when deploying my node Js application to Heroku.

Specify the local node version in your `package.json` so the server can use the same version as your local.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.13.1",
  "npm": "8.1.2"
},
"dependencies": {}
```